# ORDER BY Within JOIN Ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

2I'm trying to perform a kind os sub ordering within an order based on a join.

```
SELECT 
    w.* 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Scores] AS w
    JOIN @ScoresTable AS s on s.AreaId = w.AreaId
WHERE 
    [Id] = @Id
ORDER BY
    w.Score  -- this is where the problem is
```

`ScoresTable` is a table variable that has a specific order so my selected data from w is based on its AreaId order.

What I'm trying to do is then sort these results based on the `w.Score` column but that just seems to "override" the order I get (correctly) from the `JOIN` clause.

How do I add the `Score` order whilst still respecting the `AreaId` order established based on the `JOIN`?

I've tried using:

```
ORDER BY
    s.AreaId, w.Score
```

The JOIN results in the correct ordering based on `@ScoresTable.AreaId` order like:

```
AreaId  
5
3
6
```

Without the ORDER BY clause I get this (AreaId is ordered as required):

```
Id  Score   WheId   AreaId  ContextId
25  25      2       5       1
26  50      2       5       2
27  2       2       5       3
28  10      2       5       4
29  5       2       5       5
39  1       2       3       11
40  30      2       6       12
```

All I want to do now is order this on the Score column to get this result set (AreaId is ordered as required and sorted on Score):

```
Id  Score   WheId   AreaId  ContextId
27  2       2       5       3
29  5       2       5       5
28  10      2       5       4
25  25      2       5       1
26  50      2       5       2
39  1       2       3       11
40  30      2       6       12
```

Comment: there is no such concept as join ordering.

Comment: what you have shown is moving data from one row to another - this is not generally something you would want at all.

Comment: also - if id = @id then you are showing many id numbers - this probably is not the output of the query you posted.

Comment: Why not just add an `int identity` column to your table variable and then order by it?

Comment: add a `sortorder` column to `@ScoresTable` and sort by ` s.sortorder, w.Score`

Comment: I've tried this, but I still don't get the right results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an AreaOrder column to your @ScoresTable, so it has two columns 
AreaOrder, AreaId and then you can

```
SELECT w.* 
FROM 
[dbo].[Scores] AS w
JOIN @ScoresTable AS s on s.AreaId = w.AreaId
WHERE [Id] = @Id
ORDER BY
s.AreaOrder, w.Score
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `JOIN` order. The order you observe when there is no `ORDER BY` clause is arbitrary. It may be this with these data but once you have one or more (or less) rows or different load on the server or different distribution on the any of the joined tables or the moon gets closer to earth, the query plan may be different and the order of the result set will not be the same.

The point is that you can't and you shouldn't expect a specific ordering if you do not provide an `ORDER BY` clause.

And from the reuslts you have shown, we may guess that the ordering is based on `Id ASC`

---

Now from the limited data you have shown, it seems that you want to group the rows with same `AreaId` together and order them by `Score`. The ordering between the various values of `AreaId` though, seems strange (`5 -> 3 -> 6`).

If you want that to be affected by the `Id` column, the following may be what you are after:

```
ORDER BY
    MIN(w.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY w.AreaId),
    w.Score ;
```

(and note that if you replace the `MIN(w.id)` with `MAX(w.Id)`, you'll get the same results with the specific data. If the rest of your data comply with that, we can't know for sure.)

Answer (score 0):

I see a descending order in AreaId, so you would want to repeat that in your query. The Order By in the current query is always leading over the Order By in any subquery or view.

```
ORDER BY
    s.AreaId desc, w.Score
```

Comment: The order by AreaId is based on the order in the ScoresTable.AreaId column, it's not just a desc order, this is where my issue is coming from

Comment: your 'problem' is that you desire to place a score of 2 on a row with id 25 when it is not on that row in the first place.

Comment: @Jammer If it's not just a desc order, then you need to explain what other criteria is use for ordering. **There is no such thing as a natural order on tables**

Comment: I've just added some more information to the question.  Sorry.

Comment: @Jammer Your update shows that you want something that's not possible. again, there is no natural order on a table, so unless you specify the criteria for the ordering you can't ensure an order at all.